# How to throttle internet speed in Android

Tags: android, performance-testing

I wanted to test my Android app for user that have slow internet connection. Is there any way to do it?

Usually I am using Chrome built in feature for doing this, but I can't find similar solution for Android.

Thanks!

Comment: use android emulator or genymotion for it

Comment: run your android web work through a proxy which supports network impairment.  Example: charles proxy

Answer (score 1):

I found that the easiest way to do this in Android on a real device is through [Throttly](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.twocities.throttly) App. It worked for me good. The only thing to consider is that it uses a VPN for making the throttling.